# Injecting python/flask variable into HTML table cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a javascript function which will add a new row to an HTML table, and this works great. Except the value of the cells needs to be python/flask variables like {{variable1}}. But when I am telling the textNode of the row cell to be {{variable1}}, it prints that out literally rather than using the variable.

How can I get Javascript to put a python/flask variable into a cell which it is creating?

HTML Code

```
<table id="tbl1" class="services-impacted">
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{form.ciItem1.label}}</th>
                        <th>{{form.lvlImpact1.label}}</th>
                        <th>{{form.frmDte1.label}}</th>
                        <th>{{form.frmHr1.label}}</th>
                        <th>{{form.toDte1.label}}</th>
                        <th>{{form.toHr1.label}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{form.ciItem1}}</td>
                        <td>{{form.lvlImpact1}}</td>
                        <td>{{form.frmDte1}}</td>
                        <td>{{form.frmHr1}} {{form.frmMin1}}</td>
                        <td>{{form.toDte1}}</td>
                        <td>{{form.toHr1}} {{form.toMin1}}</td>
                        <td onclick="deleteRow(this, 'tbl1')">Delete</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p onclick="addServiceImpactRow('tbl1')">Add Service</p>
```

JavaScript

```
function addServiceImpactRow(tbl) {

var table = document.getElementById(tbl);
var tr = document.createElement("tr");

var td1 = document.createElement("td");
var text1 = document.createTextNode('{{form.ciItem1}}');
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
var text2 = document.createTextNode("{{form.lvlImpact1.label}}")
var td3 = document.createElement("td");
var text3 = document.createTextNode("{{form.frmDte1}}")
var td4 = document.createElement("td");
var text4 = document.createTextNode("{{form.frmHr1}} {{form.frmMin1}}")
var td5 = document.createElement("td");
var text5 = document.createTextNode("{{form.toDte1}}")
var td6 = document.createElement("td");
var text6 = document.createTextNode("{{form.toHr1}} {{form.toMin1}}")
var td7 = document.createElement("td");
var text7 = document.createTextNode("Delete");

td1.appendChild(text1);
td2.appendChild(text2);
td3.appendChild(text3);
td4.appendChild(text4);
td5.appendChild(text5);
td6.appendChild(text6);
td7.appendChild(text7);

tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);
tr.appendChild(td3);
tr.appendChild(td4);
tr.appendChild(td5);
tr.appendChild(td6);
tr.appendChild(td7);

table.appendChild(tr);}
```

How it looks was rendered
[image]

The pink row is what was added by the javascript, and as you can see it rendered the python/flask variables as literal text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your separate Javascript file is sent to the web-browser, which is not aware that the chunk of code should be evaluated in Python, nor has a Python engine running inside a Javascript code, nor your server-side project, so at that point your Python code is not executable.

You will need to add this into your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myInput = {
                      ciItem: "{{form.ciItem1}}", 
                      label: "{{form.lvlImpact1.label}}",
                      //other elements
                  };
</script>
```

and then use `myInput`'s members inside your `addServiceImpactRow` `function`.

Comment: Makes total sense. I will try this when I get on my computer again later and report back.

Comment: This worked as explained thanks. I now have a similar problem where those variables pass HTML, so now the HTML from the variable is being rendered as literal text instead as rendering as HTML :(

Comment: @GarethDoherty please ask a separate question about that and share the link here. However, from your description it seems that you change the inner text of an item instead of its inner html. Example: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText = '<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>'; will display this HTML as text. However, if you do document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText = '<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>'; it will be a link.